# Unable to load packages after updating Rstudio

Tags: r, package, rstudio, install.packages

I recently updated Rstudio to the latest version, but am now getting continuous error messages when I attempt to use install.packages and library().

Below is an example of what I'm seeing:

```
> install.packages("tidyverse", type="binary") ## Basic data manipulation
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/tidyverse_1.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 428925 bytes (418 KB)
downloaded 418 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\King Awesome\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaU0srW\downloaded_packages
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.2.2
```

I'm pretty certain the issue has to do with my current working directory and library paths not matching, but I do not want to start making major changes without the advice of more experienced R users for fear of making the situation more complex.

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/King Awesome/Documents/Cyclistic Raw Data/Cyclistic Slice/Cyclistic Final 10 13/Cyclistic Final PT 10 13"
```

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "T:/Gaem/R-4.2.1/library"
```

Comment: In the error itself there's some adivice: **`WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:`** Did you follow it?

Comment: I have not needed to install Rtools in the past, so I do not think this is the solution.

Comment: I attempted to install Rtools and got the following: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: As you are installing binaries then Rtools should not be needed. The end of the message says "namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded," so perhaps this is stopping a newer version gettting installed. Have oyu tries installing again in a vanilla session e.g. no workspace / libraries loaded?

Comment: ps Rtools is not a package; see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: I attempted a brand new workspace and continue to get the same error messages when attempting to install packages. I'm totally bewildered because this was never an issue in the past.

Comment: What happens with `install.packages("cli")`

Comment: you may need to `remove.packages("cli")` and all the others that will likely fail until you're good

Comment: You can also try to `remove.packages(tidyverse)`, set `options(install.packages.check.source = "no")` to prevent RStudio from attempting to install from source (with Rtools) and re`install.packages(tidyverse)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution was a full wipe. I removed all installed packages, reinstalled and now have functionality again. Good solution, @PavoDive

Comment: Glad it helped. I've never had to do that in Ubuntu, but have been there a couple of times in windows.